# How to pass data from VB.NET to ActiveX.exe?

Tags: vb.net, collections, activex

I've created a MAPI Wrapper in VB6 and compiled it as an ActiveX.exe  so I can use it in my VB.NET project. The project is a windows service that takes data from a webservice passes data to activex.exe and it creates public folder records in exchange 2003.

I was wondering if anyone know how I could pass a collection to my activex.exe?

Thanks

Comment: How is the method in the ActiveX component declared, what code do you use to call it and what's the error?

Comment: I think, I need to use collection rather than arrays, so I can find the key/value, here is how I have it.

Public Sub CreateItem(cItem As Collection)
'add it to public folders
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at the System.VisualBasic.Collection class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.collection.aspx

You might be able to take your current .net collection/array and put inside one of those collections and then send across.